# PowerBi automation and dynamic reports

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am using powerBI to create raports with customer data. The underlying data is the same, it comes from an SQL database. But this databases differs from customer to customer.

Is there a way that i could use the same raport and translations etc without adjusting it for each customer? just pulling the data from database.

Thx

simply adding other database to the connection wont work, as the tables wont work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach for this is to provision a workspace for each customer, with a copy of the report configured through a parameter to connect to the customer's database.

> To create a scalable multitenancy solution, you must be able to automate the creation of new customer tenants. Provisioning a new customer tenant typically involves writing code that uses the Power BI REST API to create a new Power BI workspace, create datasets by importing Power BI Desktop (.pbix) files, update data source parameters, set data source credentials, and set up scheduled dataset refresh. The following diagram shows how you can add Power BI items, such as reports and datasets, to workspaces to set up customer tenants.

[Develop scalable multitenancy applications with Power BI embedding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/develop-scalable-multitenancy-apps-with-powerbi-embedding)